# Block user writing to specific field within firebase table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out how to block users writing to the username field in there own data (inside users). What is the cleanest way to go about this? I guess I need to make a cloud function to check if the username is not unique and only then allow a write, but currently the rules allow the user to write to any field in users.

[image]

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".indexOn": "username",
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to **validate** if the update requested by the user is valid or not. You can achieve it by [`.validate` rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data).

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            ".indexOn": "username",
            "username": {
                ".validate": "newData.val() === data.val()"
            },
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These queries would now fail

```
UPDATE
{
  username: 23,
  displayName: "frank"
}
```

.

```
UPDATE
{
  username: 37
}
```

---

But these would be successful

```
UPDATE
{
  username: 77,
  displayName: "doug"
}
```

.

```
UPDATE
{
  displayName: "Doug"
}
```

---

**NOTE**: In case if you are creating user account on the client side itself, i.e., username would initially be provided by client itself, then the above query would fail as username didn't exist. For that you may need to change to:

```
".validate": "!data.exists() || newData.val() === data.val()"
```

Comment: Many thanks, I don't want them to be able to write the username at all. This be done by cloud function and only allows them to write unique usernames

Comment: The user can still write to the field in certain conditions though..

Comment: I dont think so. The validate rule makes sure that the field cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Simply put, `newData.val() === data.val()` ensures that old data (the original username) should be same as new data.

Comment: ok so this should be changed 
UPDATE
{
  username: 7,
  displayName: "doug"
}

Comment: I've now changed my requirement, the user can write to name but only if it's a non-duplicate of another users username, do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can use `exists` with something like `root.child(...).exists()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#referencing_data_in_other_paths

Comment: one correction , username rule needs to be nested under the id rule, you have it at same level

Comment: something like this?  "username": {
                    ".write": "root.child('users/${uid}/${data.val().username}').exists()"
                }

Comment: actually i need to query all of users to see what username is there